# Writing a shell script to install cron job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

This is the first time i am writing a shell script and i have very little information in the given timeline. Though i am reading through different tutorials but i thought to ask what i want here as well.

I want to write a shell script, which on any machine, edit the cronjob, add a new script to be executed at every 15 minutes. so basically i have to add an entry

`0,15,30,45  *  *  *  *  /home/personal/scripts/cronSqlprocedure.sh`

What i want in the shell script

- it would first change the permissions/execution rights for `cronSqlprocedure.sh`
- *edit* existing cron job and add this new entry into it.

If possible, I would like to write cronSqlprocedure through the shell script too, since it requires couple of variables which may varry from system to system.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=HEER
```

### These lines have to be configured for each machine in the `cronSqlprocedure.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
ORACLE_HOME="/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1"
ORACLE_SID="HEER"
ORACLE_USER="USER1"
ORACLE_PASSWORD="USERPASS"

echo "export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "export ORACLE_SID=$ORACLE_SID" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "rTmpDir=/tmp" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh

echo "sqlplus -s $ORACLE_USER@$ORACLE_SID/$ORACLE_PASSWORD  > $rTmpDir/deleteme.txt 2>&1 <<EOF" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "    select 1 from dual;" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "    execute another_script(1000,14);" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "EOF" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh

chmod 755 $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh

crontab -l > $PWD/sqlcorn.sh
echo "0,15,30,45 * * * * $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh" >> $PWD/sqlcorn.sh
crontab $PWD/sqlcorn.sh
```

Comment: Be careful using `crontab -l` - some versions of crontab will include a comment like "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE". You might be able to add your crontab to /etc/cron.d instead on those platforms.

Comment: Can you be specific about a version of `crontab -l` that adds the 'do not edit this file' restriction?  It seems pointless; the purpose of the `crontab` command is to allow you to edit the entries in the file.  Sure, you have to feed an edited file back into `crontab`, but ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Simple Answer to Original Question

It all seems like routine shell scripting:

```
# Clobber previous edition of script!
cronscript=$HOME/scripts/cronSqlprocedure.sh
cat <<EOF > $cronscript
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=HEER
...and whatever else is needed...
EOF
chmod u+x $cronscript

# Add to crontab
tmp=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/xyz.$$
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
crontab -l | sed '/cronSqlprocedure.sh/d' > $tmp  # Capture crontab; delete old entry
echo "0,15,30,45 * * * * $cronscript" >> $tmp
crontab < $tmp
rm -f $tmp
trap 0
```

The `trap` stuff ensures minimum damage if the user decides to interrupt, cleaning up the temporary file.  Note that the old version of the script, if any, has already been clobbered.  If you wanted to, you could arrange to create the script into another temp file, and only finish the moving when your satisfied.  I typically use I/O redirection on the `crontab` command; you can perfectly well supply the file name as an argument.

Note the escapes on `\$ORACLE_HOME` and `\$PATH` that [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) correctly pointed out should be present on `\$ORACLE_HOME` and should (perhaps) be present on `\$PATH`.  You need to decide whether you want to take the `cron`-provided (totally minimal) value of `$PATH` (in which case you want the backslash) or whether you want to use the user's current value of `$PATH` in the `cron` script.  Either could be correct - just be aware of which you choose and why.  Remember, the environment provided by `cron` is always minimal; you will get a setting for PATH, HOME, maybe TZ, probably USER and possibly LOGNAME; that may be all.  If you're not sure, try running a crontab entry which captures the environment in a file:

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/cron.env
```

You're likely to find that the file is small.  Don't forget to remove the entry after testing it.

One good thing that you're to be commended for:

- Your script (a) ensures that it sets the environment, and (b) runs a simple command from the `crontab` entry, leaving the script to do the hard work.

In my view, the entries in the `crontab` file should indeed be simple like that, invoking a purpose-built script to do the real work.

---

#### Critique of Proposed Script in the Revised Question

```
#!/bin/bash
ORACLE_HOME="/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1"
ORACLE_SID="HEER"
ORACLE_USER="USER1"
ORACLE_PASSWORD="USERPASS"
```

Thus far, no problem:

```
echo "export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "export ORACLE_SID=$ORACLE_SID" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "rTmpDir=/tmp" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh

echo "sqlplus -s $ORACLE_USER@$ORACLE_SID/$ORACLE_PASSWORD  > $rTmpDir/deleteme.txt 2>&1 <<EOF" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "    select 1 from dual;" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "    execute prvsapupd(1000,14);" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
echo "EOF" >> $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
```

This is horribly repetitive, and starting out with append is not good.  I would use:

```
cronscript=$PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
{
echo "export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME"
echo "export PATH=\$ORACLE_HOME/bin:\$PATH"
echo "export ORACLE_SID=$ORACLE_SID"
echo "rTmpDir=/tmp"

echo "sqlplus -s $ORACLE_USER@$ORACLE_SID/$ORACLE_PASSWORD  > $rTmpDir/deleteme.txt 2>&1 <<EOF"
echo "    select 1 from dual;"
echo "    execute prvsapupd(1000,14);"
echo "EOF"
} > $cronscript
```

The `{ ... }` apply the I/O redirection to the enclosed commands.  Note that there must be a semi-colon or newline before the `}`.

```
chmod 755 $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh
```

Since I have a variable for the file name, I'd use it:

```
chmod 755 $cronscript
```

Then we have a problem with repetition here, plus not cleaning up behind ourselves:

```
crontab -l > $PWD/sqlcorn.sh
echo "0,15,30,45 * * * * $PWD/sqlcronprocedure.sh" >> $PWD/sqlcorn.sh
crontab $PWD/sqlcorn.sh
```

Thus I'd write:

```
crontab=sqlcron.sh
crontab -l > $crontab
echo "0,15,30,45 * * * * $cronscript" >> $crontab
crontab $crontab
rm -f $crontab
```

I still think that `trap` is not too hard and should be used in any script that creates temporary files; however, it's your mess, not mine.  I'm not convinced the `$PWD` is needed everywhere; I left it in one name and not in the other.  If you don't supply a directory path, the `$PWD` is implied.  I also note that you're using a slightly different script name in your proposed full script from the one in the original.  As long as the names are self-consistent, there isn't a problem (and using a variable helps ensure consistency), but be careful.

I'm not sure that I'd actually do it this way, but you could also avoid the temporary file using:

```
{
crontab -l
echo "0,15,30,45 * * * * $cronscript"
} | (sleep 1; crontab -)
```

This collects the current value and appends the extra line, feeding all that into a script that sleeps for a second (to allow the first part time to complete) before feeding the results back into `crontab`.  There's a question of how reliable is the one second delay, mainly.  It's likely fine, but not guaranteed.  The temporary file is 100% reliable - I'd use it because it isn't any more complex.  (I could use parentheses around the first pair of commands; I could use braces around the second pair of commands, but I'd need to add a semi-colon between the `-` and the `)` that is replaced by `}`.)

Note that my original proposal was careful to ensure that even if the script was run multiple times, there'd be only one entry in the crontab file for the process.  Your variants do not make sure of the idempotency.

Comment: I don't want to make things overly complicated since its just for testing purposes. could you please look at my script

Comment: Careful with the HEREDOC.  $ORACLE_HOME will be expanded (probably to the empty string) unless you quote the delimiter.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer .. but thanks :)

Comment: Your script helped me workout a similar problem, however I did tweak your code slightly as instead of writing a temporary file, I used used a subshell:

    crontab <(echo "0,15,30,45 * * * * $cronscript")

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question: [Edit crontab programmatically and force the daemon to refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673143/edit-crontab-programmatically-and-force-the-daemon-to-refresh)

Changing the permissions of the file is typical shell scripting with many resources available.

For the cronjob, you'll want to essentially interface with the crontab program and feed it and entirely new cron file. You can first retrieve already configured cron jobs, add yours to the list, and then call crontab again to give it the new input file.

See the man-page for [crontab](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

SCRIPT=/home/personal/scripts/cronSqlprocedure.sh

# write the script.  
cat > $SCRIPT << 'EOF'
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=HEER
EOF

# Make the script executable
chmod +x $SCRIPT

# Add this script to the existing crontab.  This relies on your
# sed supporting -i.  if it does not, it is probably easiest to
# write a simple script that does the edit and set VISUAL to that script
if ! crontab -l | grep $SCRIPT > /dev/null; then
VISUAL='sed -i -e "\$a\
0,15,30,45 * * * * '$SCRIPT'"' crontab -e
fi
```

Comment: The first half is practically identical to my answer; I agree with that.  That seems like a contorted way to update the crontab entry, though.

Comment: @Jonathan leffler  It is definitely contorted.  I did not realize you could simply echo to crontab.  That is much cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

Create a **cron.d** file such as `/etc/cron.d/my-sql-proc`

```
0,15,30,45  *  *  *  *  root  /home/personal/scripts/cronSqlprocedure.sh
                        # 
                        # run-as user
```

Answer by **@Patrick** from **unix.stackexchange.com**:

> I would recommend using `/etc/cron.d` over `crontab`.
>
> You can place files in `/etc/cron.d` which behave like crontab entries. Though the format is slightly different.

Patrick points out it may not work on all systems, but his answer is both accepted and has the most votes.  It works well for me on debian 9 (stretch).

**source:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117244/installing-crontab-using-bash-script#117254